# Does a module exist that can fix a faulty time format?

Tags: python, datetime

I have data in the format as follows:

`12/07/2018 23:00
12/07/2018 24:00
13/07/2018 1:00`

and wanted to know if there exists a module in python that can change the `12/07/2018 24:00` to `13/07/2018 0:00`

Comment: I'm assuming that the date given is a string. Therefore it's trivial to just replace the time with the correct value: `'12/07/2018 24:00'.replace('24:00', '00:00')` I highly doubt there is a module just for this but I have seen stranger things.

Comment: I couldn't be bothered waiting and wrote a function myself. For the record it's actually quite annoying, because you can't just set the time from `24:00` to `00:00`, you have to increase the day as well. So, in worst case (ie, 31st of december), you have to change hour, day, month and year.

Comment: Ok I see your problem now. I have added an answer which should work in all cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should cover all cases for you assuming your dateformat string is static:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def fix_time(time_string):
    if '24:00' in time_string:  # Does time_string contain silly format
        _date, _ = time_string.split()  # Ignore time part since it will default to 00:00
        calendar_date= datetime.strptime(_date, '%d/%m/%Y')
        corrected_time = calendar_date + timedelta(days=1)  # Add one day to get correct date
        time_string = corrected_time.strftime('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')  # Convert back to str
    return time_string
```

Sample output:

> fix_time('31/12/2018 24:00')
> >'01/01/2019 00:00'

Code could be made more concise but this should be a good start point.